# Adding bash script execution to build process in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to add a bash script to execute during the build phase of building a project in Android Studio. I saw people talking about adding stuff in IntelliJ, but I couldn't find the settings they were talking about in Android Studio.